# Intercepting a setter for a known property of UIButton and setting its value

Tags: objective-c, iphone, properties

Suppose I was creating a property for a class, like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

If I was to create a setter for this I would use

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
  _name = name;
  // ... bla bla...
}
```

Notice the first line? I am assigning the new name to the internal variable of that property.

Now suppose I want to change the background color of a `UIButton` programmatically if the button is on the selected state.

So, I thought I could intercept the `setter` of the `selected` property, like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
  self.backgroundColor = selected ? [UIColor redColor] : [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

But there is no apparent way to set the "internal" value of that property. It will not accept `_selected = selected` and if I use `self.selected = selected` I will create a crash condition of the setting calling the setter infinite times.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an inherited property, call super:

```
[super setSelected:selected];
```

or

```
super.selected = selected;
```

Comment: B R I L L I A N T ! ! !